# don't see the cookie listed although it was definitely implemented

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to request a page of artworks. By default, 8 works are listed but I want 20 works to be listed instead. So I add a cookie to my request. Here's my code:

```
url = 'https://www.saffronart.com/search/SearchResult.aspx?all=3&exh=1&past=1&pastsl=1&sq=Akhilesh&artistid=205'
response = requests.get(url, cookies = {'UserPref': 'ps=20'})
print(response.cookies.get_dict())
```

I check by saving the response into a HTML file and see that it works: 20 works are listed per page. However, when I print out the cookies, I cannot see 
`'UserPref': 'ps=20'` listed besides the default cookies. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the URL free to hit? if yes, can you post it?

Comment: I just added the url to my question.